# Erlang Web framework and SSL?

Tags: ssl, frameworks, erlang

Can anyone either 1) tell me how to do it, or 2) point me to a resource on how to run/enable/use SSL with the Erlang Web framework?  I can't find anything in any docs or online web searches, and it looks like the last post to their mailing list is a couple of years old.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first step to enable SSL in your Erlang Web application is to configure the underlying web server. For example, if you're using Inets, you can use the file:

```
config/inets_https.conf:
```

An example Configuration File (using Apache like syntax) looks like:

```
ServerName erlangweb_https
ServerRoot docroot
DocumentRoot docroot
BindAddress 0.0.0.0 
Modules e_mod_inets
Port 443
SocketType ssl
SSLCertificateFile my.cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile my.key
SSLVerifyClient 0
```

You can also configure it using "erlang" syntax:

```
[{inets, [...]}].
```

More information about Erlang Web Server Configuration Files at:

http://wiki.erlang-web.org/Eptic/ServerConfiguration

And, specifically, for Inets:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/httpd.html

Once you have that in place, you can redirect users to HTTPS in your application controller like follows (assuming the server is using default ports):

```
{redirect, "https://" ++ e_conf:host() ++ "/" ++ wpart:fget("__path")}.
```

If your server is not using default ports, the above redirection becomes:

```
{redirect, "https://" ++ e_conf:host() ++ ":" ++ e_conf:https_port()
            ++ "/" ++ wpart:fget("__path")}.
```

For more information about configuration parameters in Erlang Web:

http://wiki.erlang-web.org/ProjectConf

To reduce verbosity, you might want to have look to [Erlang Web annotations](http://wiki.erlang-web.org/Annotations). For example 
, you could write something like:

```
?BEFORE.
https(true, _Mod, _Fun, Args) ->
    case wpart:fget("__https") of
        false ->
            Host = e_conf:host(),
            Port = e_conf:https_port(),
            Path = wpart:fget("__path"),
            Redirect = "https://" ++ Host ++ ":" ++ Port  ++ "/" ++ Path,
            {skip, {redirect, Redirect}};
        true ->
            {proceed, Args}
    end.
```

And then use it just before your controller functions to force HTTPS:

```
?HTTPS(true).
my_function(Args) ->
    ....
```

Comment: Yup, I had already done the configuration file.  Only differences are 1) I use a bind address of *, and 2) I'm not using the default ports).

I tried your redirect in the controller.  It redirects the browser and then I get an internal server error.

All the supervisor processes look like they come up fine.  I don't see any errors or failures there.

I am using inets, and also Windows (usage of Windows is only for dev, not production).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you paste the Internal Server Error you're getting?

Comment: This is what pops up on the web page (nothing pops up on the interactive shell):  

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator unknown@unknown, and inform them of the time the error occurred and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

Comment: Strange, I added the redirect to the dispatch.conf and it seems to "work" now.  However, I cannot access the server with https:// at all.  I have to use normal http:// with normal port, but it seems to do a redirect to the https:  But https never shows up anywhere in browser, just normal http.  Is this the way it should work?  How do I, or the user, know anything is being encrypted?

Comment: Whoops - nevermind.  It is NOT working at all, I was wrong :-(